# How do I access Twitter in other languages?

Tags: twitter

So, Twitter has the following menu options: Home, Search, Spaces, Notifications, and Messages. In Spanish, we would have Inicio, Buscar, Espacios, Notificacions, and Mensajes. And the same applies for all languages. Can anyone help me access Twitter in other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile devices such as iOS or Android, you need to change your device language and Twitter will automatically change the language on the app.

On iOS:

- Open Settings
- Tap General
- Scroll down and tap Language & Region
- Tap iPhone Language
- Pick your language

On Android, it varies per device, so you will have to check out your manufacturer's website. It is usually in Settings under the Language & Region section.

On Twitter for Web:

- Click the more icon and select Settings and privacy
- Click on the Accessibility, display and languages tab
- Click Languages
- Under Display language, click and choose your preferred language
- Click Save